# Jboss undeploy application missing sha

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I use wildfly Master-domain. When I deploy some application, in domain.xml is created sha for example:

> dd234b0920c094b633ebb38c9432dee9ea96ecfc

and is too created content in

> /opt/wildfly/domain/data/content/dd/234b0920c094b633ebb38c9432dee9ea96ecfc/

But when I undeploy application via management console, content from

> /opt/wildfly/domain/data/content/

will disappear. When I need restart wildfly I get message:

```
[Host Controller] 15:34:01,768 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "APPLICATION.ear")]) - failure description: "WFLYDC0058: No deployment content with hash dd234b0920c094b633ebb38c9432dee9ea96ecfc is available in the deployment content repository for deployment 'APPLICATION.ear'. This is a fatal boot error. To correct the problem, either restart with the --admin-only switch set and use the CLI to install the missing content or remove it from the configuration, or remove the deployment from the xml configuraiton file and restart."[Host Controller] 15:34:01,815 FATAL [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYHC0034: Host Controller boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.[Host Controller] 15:34:01,817 FATAL [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYHC0178: Aborting with exit code 99
```

In domain.xml file exist sha1.

server log:

> 2018-03-15 10:30:21,518 DEBUG [org.wildfly.extension.batch] (MSC service thread 1-1) Removing batch environment; ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.APPLICATION-1.9.3.ear:main" from Service Module Loader
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,527 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) Setting custom ConstraintValidatorFactory of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,528 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) Setting custom MessageInterpolator of type org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,528 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) Setting custom TraversableResolver of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,528 DEBUG [org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) Setting custom ParameterNameProvider of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.DefaultParameterNameProvider
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,532 DEBUG [org.wildfly.extension.batch] (MSC service thread 1-3) Removing batch environment; ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.APPLICATION-1.9.3.ear.APPLICATION-web-1.9.3.war:main" from Service Module Loader
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,588 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) unRegistering EJB client context for classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.APPLICATION-1.9.3.ear.APPLICATION-ejb-1.9.3.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,591 DEBUG [org.wildfly.extension.batch] (MSC service thread 1-2) Removing batch environment; ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.APPLICATION-1.9.3.ear.APPLICATION-ejb-1.9.3.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,599 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /APPLICATION
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,630 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(APPLICATION-web)
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,651 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0010: Stopping weld service for deployment APPLICATION-1.9.3.ear
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,667 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) unRegistering EJB client context for classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.APPLICATION-1.9.3.ear.APPLICATION-web-1.9.3.war:main" from Service Module Loader
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,742 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: APPLICATION-web-1.9.3.war) in 270ms
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,743 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: APPLICATION-ejb-1.9.3.jar) in 271ms
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,744 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10) loom-devsync1-datasource: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@228b594d[userName=user]) [0/30]
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,746 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10) loom-devsync1-datasource: returnConnection(29207e12, false) [0/30]
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,762 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment APPLICATION-1.9.3.ear (runtime-name: APPLICATION-1.9.3.ear) in 291ms
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,847 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1) loom-devsync1-datasource: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@228b594d[userName=user]) [0/30]
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,848 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2) loom-devsync1-datasource: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@228b594d[userName=user]) [0/30]
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,851 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.poouseel.strategy.OnePool] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1) loom-devsync1-datasource: returnConnection(29207e12, false) [0/30]
>   2018-03-15 10:30:21,852 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2) loom-devsync1-datasource: returnConnection(2ffe1f48, false) [0/30]
>   2018-03-15 10:30:22,116 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "APPLICATION-1.9.3.ear" (runtime-name: "APPLICATION-1.9.3.ear")
>   2018-03-15 10:30:22,123 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /opt/wildfly/data/content/dd/234b0920c094b633ebb38c9432dee9ea96ecfc/content

and environment: Debian wheezy, wildlfy 10.1.0 FINAL Core version: 2.8.27.Final

I need to solve problem with deleting content from /opt/wildfly/domain/data/content/.

The content should by stay in this folder. Application can by again deploy.

Comment: Could you define your environment ? Do you have any log message during undeployment on the server side ?

Comment: Did you disabled the deployment before? Are there multiple deployments with the same archive? I remember a problem when you undeploy one application but the same jar is used for other deployments as well.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple deployments with the same archive. But in this case application is deployed only one.
Can you please me more describe "Did you disabled the deployment before?" Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the latest version which is WildFly 12